# User-defined stored procedure not visible in Master Data Services Business Rules configurator

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

I am working with SQL Server 2022 Master Data Services, and need to deploy some custom SQL scripts to include in business rules.  I have created some functions and some stored procedures, all in the usr schema.

The functions that I have created are visible in the web UI, and can be used as the condition for a business rule, but the stored procedures are not visible in the Then or Else section - the "*User defined scripts*" section of the drop-down is empty.

I found a suggestion that I need to grant EXECUTE authority on the **usr** schema to **mds_br_user**, but that user is already the owner of the schema.  There is an old MDS database where the procedures ARE visible in the business rules, but I can't find any differences in the permissions.

The procedure has been created with the input parameters defined in the docs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usr].[myProc]
(@MemberIDList mdm.[MemberId] READONLY  
 ,@ModelName NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@VersionName NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@EntityName NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@BusinessRuleName NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )
```

What changes do I need to make to let me use my stored procedures in business rules?